# Opening google assistant on Android in Lens mode

Tags: android, android-intent, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to open the google assistant from my application in lens mode.  I can use `startActivity( Intent( Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND ).setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ) )` to open it and have it listen for commands, but I would like to open it and immediately go to the lens activity.  Is there a string that I can use that opens the google assistant without activating the voice command, like `"com.google.googleassistant"`.  And is there an action that I can set to open lens directly?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there isn't a way to open lens directly. Sorry Sam.